# neo4j: cypher if else

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 3 type of nodes: FOLDER, TYPE_A, TYPE_B and one relationship: CONTAINS;

I am having difficulty in writing cypher, in a single query, to fetch this:

```
if(folder CONTAINS TYPE_A) {
   return ids of TYPE_A
} else if (folder CONTAINS TYPE_B) {
  then return ids of TYPE_B
} else {
  return empty array;
}
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `apoc.do.when` to fetch the `ids` of `TYPE_B` conditionally, when no `TYPE_A` nodes are present. Like this:

```
MATCH (n:FOLDER)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:CONTAINS]-(m:TYPE_A)
WITH n, collect(id(m)) AS typeAIds
CALL apoc.do.when(
   size(typeAIds) = 0, 
   'OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:CONTAINS]-(m:TYPE_B) WITH n, collect(id(m)) AS typeBIds RETURN typeBIds', 
   'RETURN [] as typeBIds', 
   {n: n}
) 
YIELD value
RETURN n, typeAIds + value.typeBIds AS ids
```

In this query, we first fetch the `TYPE_A` node ids and collect them in an array. If those `ids` are not present, then we fetch `TYPE_B` node ids, within [`apoc.do.when`](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/5/overview/apoc.do/apoc.do.when/). Finally, we return the output. This is a bit more optimized as we only fetch the relationships if needed. You will need to install, `APOC` library for this query to work. Another variant of the same query is this:

```
MATCH (n:FOLDER)
CALL apoc.do.when(
    SIZE([(n)-[:CONTAINS]-(:TYPE_A) | 1]) <> 0, 
    'OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:CONTAINS]-(m:TYPE_A) WITH n, collect(id(m)) AS typeAIds RETURN typeAIds', 
    'RETURN [] as typeAIds', 
    {n: n}
)
YIELD value AS v1
CALL apoc.do.when(
    SIZE([(n)-[:CONTAINS]-(:TYPE_B) | 1]) <> 0 AND SIZE(v1.typeAIds) = 0, 
    'OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:CONTAINS]-(m:TYPE_B) WITH n, collect(id(m)) AS typeBIds RETURN typeBIds', 
    'RETURN [] as typeBIds', 
    {n: n}
)
YIELD value AS v2
RETURN n, v1.typeAIds + v2.typeBIds AS ids
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! What is that "| 1" in the query does?

Comment: @Arjun the part `[(n)-[:CONTAINS]-(:TYPE_B) | 1]` is a list comprehension, what it does is for any match on the left side of the bar `|` it pushed the element on the right side of the `|` into the list.

Answer (score 1):

For a specific folder, one option is:

```
MATCH (n:FOLDER)
WHERE n.key = 1
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)--(m)
WITH DISTINCT labels(m) AS type, COLLECT (id(m)) AS res
ORDER BY type[0]
LIMIT 1
RETURN res
```

Which returns the expected output on the sample data:

```
MERGE (a1:FOLDER {key:1})    
MERGE (a2:TYPE_A {key:2})   
MERGE (a3:TYPE_A {key:3})
MERGE (a4:TYPE_B {key:4})
MERGE (b1:FOLDER {key:5})
MERGE (b2:TYPE_B {key:6})
MERGE (c1:FOLDER {key:7})

MERGE (a1)-[:CONTAINS]-(a2)
MERGE (a1)-[:CONTAINS]-(a3)
MERGE (a1)-[:CONTAINS]-(a4)
MERGE (b1)-[:CONTAINS]-(b2)
```

If you want the results for all your folders in one query, you can do:

```
MATCH (n:FOLDER)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)--(m)
WITH DISTINCT labels(m) AS type, COLLECT (id(m)) AS res, id(n) AS folder
ORDER BY type[0]
WITH DISTINCT folder, COLLECT (res) AS res
RETURN res[0], folder
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return `a` and `b` lists (we return both lists, in case some folders or even some "type" nodes contain both labels):

```
MATCH (f:FOLDER)-[:CONTAINS]->(ty:TYPE_A|TYPE_B)
WHERE f.id = 123
WITH REDUCE(s={a:[], b:[]}, t IN COLLECT(ty) |
  CASE WHEN ALL(w IN ['TYPE_A','TYPE_B'] WHERE w IN LABELS(t))
    THEN {a: s.a+t, b: s.b+t}
  CASE WHEN 'TYPE_A' IN LABELS(t)
    THEN {a: s.a+t, b: s.b}
  ELSE {a: s.a, b: s.b+t} END) AS x
RETURN x.a AS a, x.b AS b
```

The query uses the [predicate label expression](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/#label-expressions) `(ty:TYPE_A|TYPE_B)` to search for "type" nodes that end in either of the 2 desired labels. Support for such expressions were introduced in neo4j 5.0.

The [REDUCE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-reduce) function is used to iterate through the matching "type" nodes to generate the lists. And a [CASE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/#query-syntax-case) expression is used to do the `IF/THEN/ELSE` processing on each node.